# Search dynamic JSON by id

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON with the following structure:

```
{
 "root": {
    "containers": [
       {
         "id": UNIQUE_ID,
         ...
         "child": [
           {
             "id": UNIQUE_ID,
             ...
             "child": [...]
           }
         ]
       },

       {
         "id": UNIQUE_ID,
         ...
         "child": [...]
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

root.containers and root.containers.child have the same structure. The thing is that I can have infinite nesting and I don't know beforehand what is the total number of child nodes, since they are added to this JSON dynamically.

I need a function that returns me only the specific object with the given ID as parameter. So it has to dive into the JSON until it finds the child with that ID. I've tried something with .filters but I can't figure out how to search deeper. Probably some search algorithm that I've never implemented in javascript before...

Can someone give me an idea how can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: 1) write code 2) execute code 3) debug code. We (maybe) help with #3. The other two are entirely your responsibility.

Comment: Arbitrarily nested objects are easy to traverse if you use recursion. Just loop through the children, and make a recursive call if a child has any children.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, ideas is all I'm asking really.. Sorry if what I wrote made you think that I'm asking to do my job for me. I just don't have any more clues how to do that. I spent several days on this so I came here trying to find someone to enlight me, maybe give me some path to follow.. I also tried to search similar problems here with no success. Thats all.

Comment: @GabrielPereira "idea" questions are really hard to answer in this setting. SO is not a forum for design discussions. You need to ask specific questions that have objective answers. This generally means writing the code yourself, and then posting it if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you need is:

```
function findById(data, id){
    var found;
    data.forEach(function(o){
        if(found){
            return;
        }
        found = o.id === id && o || o.child && findById(o.child, id);
    });

    return found;
}
```

And it would be used in this way:

```
findById(data.root.containers, 1)
```

Check and run the following snippet. it has some tests, including one case to fail.

```js
var data = {
 "root": {
    "containers": [
       {
         "id": 1,
         "child": [
           {
             "id": 2,
             "child": [{
              id: 3
             }, {
              id: 4
             }]
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         "id": 5,
         "child": [{
            id: 6
          }]
       },
       {
         "id": 7,
         "child": []
       }
    ]
  }
};

function findById(data, id){
 var found;
 data.forEach(function(o){
  if(found){
   return;
  }
  found = o.id === id && o || o.child && findById(o.child, id);
 });

 return found;
}

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].forEach(function(v){
 console.log('==== Searching for:', v);
  console.log(findById(data.root.containers, v));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function like this (https://jsfiddle.net/17qLjufc/):

```
//this is just a function to check for null or undefined
var notEmpty = function(something){
    if(typeof(something) !== 'undefined' && something !== null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//this is a recursive function that does the search in dept indefinetly (supposing that all the nodes from the containers node on just have child properties)
var findNodeById = function (node, id){
    if(notEmpty(node) && notEmpty(node.id) && node.id == id)
        return node;
    else{
        if(notEmpty(node) && notEmpty(node.child)){
            for (var i = 0 ; i < node.child.length; i++){
                var found = findNodeById(node.child[i], id);
                if(found != null)
                    return found;
                }
            }
        }
    return null;
}

//this is going through the containers children and call the search for each of them until the first is found.
var searchById = function(root, id){
    var found;
    if(notEmpty(root) && notEmpty(root.containers)){
        for(var i = 0; i < root.containers.length; i++){
            found = findNodeById(root.containers[i], id);
            if(found !== null){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```